# Flash, Floating DIV, and Input Boxes Bug

Tags: flash, firefox, textfield, css-position

So I have a Firefox bug here and am wondering if there is a way around it.  I pulled it up on Safari and am yet to check Chrome or IE.

I have a flash movie (wmode=opaque) in the middle of the page, and a button that calls a floating window (position:absolute;z-index:999) that allows you to login or signup.  Which looks fine...everything float's over the window properly.  But when I click a TextField to begin entering text...the Flash Movie shows through the floating div every time the cursor blinks.

Now like I said this only happens on Firefox so far, but is there any way around this???

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and found a workaround right now.
I discovered that the problem occurs when the focus is already in the input, and it works when the input/textarea gets the focus the first time.

SOLUTION: bind a click on the input/textarea and make a blur followed by a focus. it works as expected!

with jQuery:

```
$('input,textarea').click(function() {
jQuery(this).blur().focus();
})
```

In html should be something like (not tested)

```
<textearea onClick="this.blur();this.focus()">
```